# How does diamond operator work with array as argument

Tags: arrays, string, perl, io, daemon

I have got an array `@address` whose zero element contains some strings.
I can not find an example diamond operator works with @array as argument.
(how it 'split' strings?)

```
use Mojo::Loader qw/ data_section /;

my @address =  data_section 'main', 'address_strings';


while( my $line = <@address> ) {
  print $line;
}


1;


__DATA__
@@ address_strings
"010101, УУУ обл., м. Тернопіль, вул. ВВВ, буд. 0101, 01"
"020202, ЛЛЛ обл., ААА район, село ФФФ, ВУЛИЦЯ ШШШ, будинок 01"
"030303, м.ЮЮЮ, ЮЮЮ р-н, вул. ЛЛЛ, буд.01, офіс 01"
```

**UPD**
Reading from doc `<>` operator allow GLOB or filehandle, but in my case that is **just array of one string**.

```
my @arr = <<TEXT;
many
lines
TEXT

while( my $line =  <@arr> ) {
    print ">>$line<<\n";
}
```

Does `<>` do something magic for this case? You can notice, that lines are splitted

Answer (score 5):

That's ... not what the diamond operator does, which is why you can't find any examples.

You only need:

```
foreach my $line ( @address ) { 
  print $line;
}
```

The `<>` denotes reading from a file handle, and `@address` is not a file handle. It isn't even an array of file handles.

You could theoretically do

```
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) { 
   print $line; 
}
```

Which because `DATA` is a file handle, `<>` triggers a single record read from that filehandle. (record boundary defaults to linefeed, but you can change `$/`)

This wouldn't make sense given what you're doing with Mojo, I merely give it as an example of how it *should* work.

Comment: Note that reading DATA directly would also read the `@@ address_strings` which Mojo::Loader's data_section probably hides.

Comment: Yes, good point. Wouldn't make a lot of sense for the OP; I'll clarify that it's meant as an example.

Comment: @Sobrique: I understand that official doc allows only GLOB or filehandle as argument, but in my case there is array of one string. And I can not find where this is documented

Answer (score 3):

`<>` is potentially two different operators, `glob` or `readline`.  If what is in it is a simple scalar variable or a bareword, it is a readline operation, and the argument is the filehandle to use.  Otherwise, it is a glob operation and the argument is treated as whitespace separated filenames (or filename wildcards to expand).

When `<>` is a glob operation, it is treated as a double-quotish context, and arrays are interpolated by joining with `$"` (which defaults to space).  So `<@x>` is `glob "@x"` is `glob join $", @x`.  So assuming `$"` is unchanged and there are no wildcards in the elements of `@x`, it is very much like just `split ' ', "@x"`, joining all the elements together with spaces and then splitting the results on whitespace.

Comment: in my case argument is neither `glob`, neither `filehandle`, but there is no error

Comment: @muhana it is doing a glob.  not sure why you think it isn't?  glob vs readline is determined purely syntactically; if what is in the <> isn't a simple scalar variable or a bareword, it is a glob

Comment: Can you look at updated question. I do not understand why my `@arr` is `GLOB`. It is array of one string.

Comment: @muhana: again, <> always is a glob except if what is inside is either a bareword (e.g. `<FH>`) or a simple scalar variable (e.g. `<$fh>`).  this is determined when the code is compiled, not run, so it has no idea how many elements there are in the array; it only depends on what your code looks like.  anything but those two is a glob.  which as explained often behaves like `split ' ', "@arr"` would (though if split is what you actually want, you should do that)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [perldoc -f glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

A typical usage would be:

```perl
my @suffix = qw(*.yaml *.json);
my @yaml = <@suffix>;
# or directly
my @yamlfiles = <*.yaml *.json>;
```

So be careful when using it for data that could potentially be a filename wildcard ;-)

Comment: in my case argument is not `glob`.